# How to access browser local storage when writing body element to include css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a left navigation menu that can be expanded and collapsed by user. In order to maintain the state of the menu (expanded or collapsed) between page refreshes I set a TempData variable whenever the user clicks the expand/collapse button and peek at the variable to include it in the class attribute of the body element. This works fine however I want to move away from using TempData in order to help my app become more stateless.

I have achieved similar functionality by writing to browser local storage and reading from it on document load. The problem with this is that the page always flickers because it will first load the page in expanded mode (without the class in body tag) then collapse the menu once the javascript runs to add the required class. This creates a very annoying user experience each time they load a page.

Is there any way to have local storage read directly into the class attribute or a different approach to achieve this instead? Note that I want to avoid writing/reading from database if possible to avoid database call on every page load.

Here's what I have now which works but includes TempData variable...

**_Layout page**

```
<body class="hold-transition fixed sidebar-mini @TempData.Peek("MenuState")">
```

**JQuery/JavaScript when menu button is clicked**

```
$('#left-menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    var menuState = '';
    if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse') === false) {
        menuState = 'sidebar-collapse';
    }
    $.post('/Header/ToggleMenu', { state: menuState });
});
```

**Controller action**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ToggleMenu(string state)
{
    TempData["MenuState"] = state;
    return Ok();
}
```

Here's what I have tried to replace the TempData variable...

**_Layout page**

```
<body class="hold-transition fixed sidebar-mini">
```

**JQuery/JavaScript when menu button is clicked**

```
$('#left-menu-toggle').on('click', function () {
    if ($('body').hasClass('sidebar-collapse')) {
        localStorage.setItem('menuState', 'sidebar-collapse');
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem('menuState');
    }
});
```

**JQuery/JavaScript when page loads - this causes the menu to always load in expanded mode then collapse if required which the transition is annoyingly visible to user**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem('menuState') !== null) {
        $('body').addClass('sidebar-collapse');
    }
    else {
        $('body').removeClass('sidebar-collapse');
    }
});
```

Comment: add the collapsed class to the body in the html so it starts collapsed?

Comment: @John this just reverses the effect but the ugly transition still exists unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by setting and removing cookies as below...

**_Layout**

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("MenuState", out string menuState);
}

...

<body class="hold-transition fixed sidebar-mini @menuState">

...
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ToggleMenu(string menuState)
{
    if (menuState != null)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Append("MenuState", menuState);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete("MenuState");
    }
    return Ok();
}
```